# Seperating data based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have data as below

```
Account-Num    Date             Dr      Cr
123          29-04-2020         100
123          28-04-2020                 50
258          28-04-2020         75    
258          29-04-2020                 30
```

How do I separate data of each account number and save it on new sheet or file.

I have tried and came up with following code

```
import pandas as pd
soa = pd.read_excel('ubl.xlsx')
acc = '218851993'
df2 = soa.where(soa['ACCT_NO']== acc)
df2.to_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/mcb/D/HBL/UBL/' + acc + '.csv',index=False)
```

but it is generating following error.

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: If you haven't done anything yet, start with researching on filters or advanced filters (see [Copy Data to Another Worksheet with Advanced Filter](https://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/)). Give it a try yourself before asking us to do all the work for you.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. I have tried Advance Filter but can't reach my desired result. I just need a lead. Not the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table.

In the rows put all your dates. In the columns, put the account numbers. You can then add the DR and CR columns to your values, making sure you sum them.

This will then aggregate all information, per date, for each account number.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried this. But data is pretty much complex and I need separate files for each account. Is there any other way.